# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Tags: numpy, reshape

I used a dataset "ex1data1.txt", but when I am running it to convert, it is showing the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-7c523f7ba9e1> in <module>()
      1 # Converting loaded dataset into numpy array
      2 
----> 3 X = np.concatenate((np.ones(len(population)).reshape(len(population), 1), population.reshape(len(population),1)), axis=1)
      4 
      5 

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

The code is given below:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Loading Dataset
with open('ex1data1.txt') as csvfile:
    population, profit = zip(*[(float(row['Population']), float(row['Profit'])) for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile)])

# Creating DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Population'] = population
df['Profit'] = profit

# Plotting using Seaborn
sns.lmplot(x="Population", y="Profit", data=df, fit_reg=False, scatter_kws={'s':45})

# Converting loaded dataset into numpy array
X = np.concatenate((np.ones(len(population)).reshape(len(population), 1), population.reshape(len(population),1)), axis=1)

y = np.array(profit).reshape(len(profit), 1)

# Creating theta matrix , theta = [[0], [0]]
theta = np.zeros((2, 1))

# Learning rate
alpha = 0.1
# Iterations to be taken
iterations = 1500
# Updated theta and calculated cost
theta, cost = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, iterations)
```

I don't know how to solve this reshape problem. Can anyone tell how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is `population`?  To use `reshape` method it has to be an array, but the error says it's a tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your definition, `population` is a tuple. I'd suggest two options, the first is converting it to an array, i.e.

```
population = np.asarray(population)
```

Alternatively, you can use the DataFrame column `.values` attribute, which is essentially a numpy array:

```
X = np.concatenate((np.ones(len(population)).reshape(len(population), 1), df['Population'].values.reshape(len(population),1)), axis=1)
```